# Get method returns Nulls when using Include on EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following get method which returns out of stock items in my database. My database is broken up into 2 tables, one called stock and one called Issue. My stock table is joined on the issue table (Both of them have IssueId in them)

When i run the following code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Stock> GetOutOfStock(int page)
    {
        var stock = (from s in _context.Set<Stock>().Cast<Stock>()
                    where s.AvailableQty == 0
                    orderby s.Issue.PublicationDate descending
                    select s).Skip(25 * page).Take(25);
        //.Include(s => s.Issue)
        return stock;
    }
```

I get this as my output:

```
  {
"stockReferenceId": 32681,
"issueId": 7980,
"condition": "Fine",
"availableQty": 0,
"price": 51.94,
"comments": null,
"issue": null,
"supplierOrders": [],
"supplierQuotes": []
```

}

but as soon as i Include my Issue table with the following code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Stock> GetOutOfStock(int page)
    {
        var stock = (from s in _context.Set<Stock>().Cast<Stock>()
                    where s.AvailableQty == 0
                    orderby s.Issue.PublicationDate descending
                    select s).Include(s => s.Issue).Skip(25 * page).Take(25);
        //
        return stock;
    }
```

I get the following output

```
 {
"StockReferenceId": 0,
"IssueId": 0,
"Condition": "string",
"AvailableQty": 0,
"Price": 0,
"Comments": "string",
"Issue": {
  "IssueId": 0,
  "Title": "string",
  "PublicationDate": "2020-02-17T08:55:27.501Z",
  "Publisher": "string",
  "SeriesNumber": 0,
  "Description": "string",
  "CoverImage": "string",
  "ComicCreators": [
    {
      "IssueId": 0,
      "CreatorId": 0,
      "CreatorRole": "string",
      "Creator": {
        "CreatorId": 0,
        "Name": "string",
        "CountryOfResidence": "string",
        "TaxReferenceNumber": "string",
        "EmailAddress": "string",
        "ComicCreators": [
          null
        ]
      }
    }
```

My domain tables look like this:
Stock:

```
 public Stock()
    {
        //Cart = new HashSet<Cart>();
        //OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
        SupplierOrders = new HashSet<SupplierOrders>();
        SupplierQuotes = new HashSet<SupplierQuotes>();
    }

    public int StockReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int? IssueId { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public short? AvailableQty { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public Issues Issue { get; set; }
```

and my Issue table looks like this:

```
    public partial class Issues
{
    public Issues()
    {
        ComicCreators = new HashSet<ComicCreators>();
        Stock = new HashSet<Stock>();
    }

    public int IssueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public short? SeriesNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CoverImage { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ComicCreators> ComicCreators { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Stock> Stock { get; set; }


}
```

How do i get my get request to return my stock and Issue in my Json?

Comment: Try remove `Cast<Stock>()` or use `_context.Set<Stock>().Include(s => s.Issue).Cast<Stock>()`. I think the problem is in using `Include` after `Cast`.

Comment: @Vlad Tried that, both of them and it doesnt work